# How to get the dictionary value by selection tableview cell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview, dictionary

I have two arrays and one Dictionary which contains number and countries as shown in ViewDidLoad method.
When the user click on the particular cell,the country will be displayed in the Console.
how can i do that.
Thanks in advance.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
arrayofNumbers = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"1",@"2",@"3",@"4",@"5", nil];

arrayofCountries = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"India",              @"America",@"Pakistan",@"Germany",@"Australia",nil];

dictOfCountries = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:arrayofNumbers   forKeys:arrayofCountries];

}

-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath
{ 
    NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath = [tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath];
    NSLog(@"%@", cell.textLabel.text);
}
```

Comment: Please fix your code formatting (indents and get rid of all the extra blank lines).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why creating a `NSDictionary` and extra `NSArray` to hold your indexPath? You can access selected country by its index in `arrayofCountries` array.

Change your `viewDidLoad` method to this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
arrayofCountries = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"India",@"America",@"Pakistan",@"Germany",@"Australia",nil];
}
```

And implement `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` delegate method as follows

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath { 

// when user select a cell in your tableView the indexPath of this cell is the
// index of your dataSource array in  your case this is arrayOfCountries 

    NSLog(@"Selected Country ----> %@", [arrayOfCountries objectAtIndex:[indexPath.row]]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath { 

    NSLog(@"%@", arrayOfCountries[indexPath.row]);
}
```